# Is it possible in W3C's XML Schema language (XSD) to allow a series of elements to be in any order but still limit occurrences?

Tags: xml, schema, xsd

I know about `all` and `choice`, but they don't account for a case where I do want some elements to be able to occur more than once, such as:

```
<Root>
    <ThingA/>
    <ThingB/>
    <ThingC/>
    <ThingC/>
    <ThingC/>
</Root>
```

I could use `sequence`, but I'd prefer to allow these children to be in any order. I could use `any`, but then I couldn't have more than one `ThingC`. I could use `choice`, but then I couldn't limit `ThingA` and `ThingB` to 0 or 1.

I think I may have read somewhere that this was either difficult or impossible in XSD, but might be possible with RELAX NG. I don't remember where I read that, unfortunately.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's right: you can't do what you want to do in XML Schema, but you can in RELAX NG with:

```xml
<element name="Root">
  <interleave>
    <element name="ThingA"><empty /></element>
    <element name="ThingB"><empty /></element>
    <oneOrMore><element name="ThingC"><empty /></element></oneOrMore>
  </interleave>
</element>
```

Your options in XML Schema are:

- add a preprocessing step that normalises your input XML into a particular order, and then use `<xs:sequence>`
- use `<xs:choice>`, and add extra validation (for example using Schematron) to check that there's not more than one `<ThingA>` or `<ThingB>`
- decide to fix the order of the elements in your markup language

It turns out that the third is usually the best option; there's usually not much cost for generators of XML to output elements in a particular order, and not only does it help validation but it also aids consumption of the XML if the order can be known in advance.